# eZPuzblish regerate ezurl table

Tags: url-rewriting, ezpublish

**The Problem**

The url-policy for one of my projects has changed. They want to have lowercase URL's (plain old style). Example:

```
http://www.myproject.tld/archive/articles/the-thruth-is-in-here
```

For now the URL's are like this:

```
http://www.myproject.tld/Archive/Articles/The-thruth-is-in-here
```

**The concept**

I will use the URL transformation group "urlalias_compat" to make them lowercaseand compatible to old systems. I have set the following Setting in *site.ini.append*:

```
[URLTranslator]
TransformationGroup=urlalias_compat
```

This works fine for new published objects. The solution satisfies all my URL-bahavior wishes, but...

**The Question**

How can i regenrate the eZURL-Table?

All Nodes which were published before the change are saved in the old URL-scheme (1.3 million Articles) If i re-publish them, they will have the mew URL-scheme, but i need a solution which does not make so much work to do. It's inpossible to deploy such a change and repulish all Objects in the whole eZPublish instance.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dedicated script is shipped with eZ Publish, to be run every time the TransformationGroup setting is updated.

Detailed explanations can be found on the official documentation page, right here : 
http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Configuration-files/site.ini/URLTranslator/TransformationGroup

Cheers,